# preselect foreigen content in dynamic populated dropdown in HTML/Bootstrap/angular2

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I'm facing the issue to preselect an entry in a dynamic populated dropdown.

It's about a filed for choosing a language. The possible languages are populated dynamically.
I want to have a preselected value as a hint, which is not included in this list. E.g. "Choose language"

Here is my code what I thougt it might work:

```
<select id="languageSelection" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" (ngModelChange)="onLanguageChange($event)">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose language</option>
    <option class="" *ngFor="let l of languages" [ngValue]="l">{{l}}</option>
</select>
```

I get the list of the languages, but there is a language preselected.
If I remove the "hidden"-tag the "Choose language" appears grayed out in the list. But a language is preselected, too.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[(ngModel)]` is overriding the selected attribute. A workaround would be to set a predefined value to your variable `selectedLanguage`, and use that in the options as default value, so for example:

**TS:**

```
selectedLanguage = 0;
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="languageSelection" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" (ngModelChange)="onLanguageChange($event)">
    <option [disabled]="true" value="0">Choose Language</option>
    <option class="" *ngFor="let l of languages" [ngValue]="l">{{l}}</option>
</select>
```

That should do it :)